# Why are some answers posted as comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)
>   [Is it in bad form to answer a question with another user's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/is-it-in-bad-form-to-answer-a-question-with-another-users-comment)

I've started to see more and more people posting comments (under the question, not on another answer) which perfectly answer the question. Here's a [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490564/tool-to-detect-non-dotted-relative-imports-in-python).

Is there a reason for this? Is it encouraged or discouraged? Would it be ethical to re-post it as an answer with reference to the original commenter?

Comment: @random That question only covers the general area of posting answers as comments. It doesn't cover either of the example case I provided nor the follow-on questions "Is it encouraged or discouraged? Would it be ethical to re-post it as an answer with reference to the original commenter?"

Comment: You might be able to open the subquestions as a new question, reference the ones marked as "duplicates" and explain why they are not sufficient to answer the new question. I don't know if those would be closed too, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer with a comment when I'm not really sure I'm right, but want to offer a hunch. Often it's in cases where the relevant technologies are alien to me.

Comment: While I partially agree in that case, the [example I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490564/tool-to-detect-non-dotted-relative-imports-in-python) is quite a confident answer.