# Plagiarism tag to identify plagiarized posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, plagiarism

Is there any way we can introduce a tag in Stack Overflow, where the community can tag any question, answer or comment as [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism), so that the poster can take a note of it and correct his post accordingly?

Comment: Tags shouldn't be used in this manner, only to describe the content of the question and/or expect content answers.  But what is the end goal of this request?  Are you trying to prevent people from plagiarizing other sites, other users, other questions?

Comment: A far better idea would be to just leave a (polite) comment asking the OP to include a link to their source, and to use the Block Quote tag for quoted content, so it gets attributed correctly to the author that wrote the content.

Comment: this question has the `plagiarism` tag.  It must be plagarism

Comment: @random that was the fastest [meta-tag:status-declined] tag I recall seeing before.

Comment: Plagiarism in answers is a much bigger problem than in questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most important thing to do in cases of plagiarism is [to edit it and/or flag it for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

If your goal is to alert the OP (in case it was a mistake that can be corrected), you should leave a *comment*, not a tag. Tags aren't used for this purpose, for multiple reasons:

- [Meta tags are explicitly discouraged on SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- An offended user can edit the question to remove the tag (and could probably start an edit war)
- A [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism) tag gives no information other than an accusation. Which part was plagiarized, and where from?

Beyond that, what usefulness does a tag have that a comment doesn't? Anyone who has enough reputation to retag a post can also comment on it. Any asker who ignores comments about plagiarism would surely also ignore a tag. And we're not encouraging users to follow the [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism) tag to read all the plagiarized questions on the site.