# When to credit someone else for an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

When answering a question, is it appropriate to copy large amounts of content (from somewhere other than SO) and present that as your answer?

For example, yesterday a poster asked for clarification about a lengthy blog entry.  Someone else answered by copying a couple of paragraphs from the blog entry.  No mention was made that content was not his.  This answer immediately received multiple down-votes until it was removed.

I then looked at this user's history and found other cases where he had copied large chunks of code from online documentation.  In each case he again did not indicate the origin of the code.

Something feels wrong about this behavior.  I would think that you should at least state up front that code came from elsewhere, and to provide a link.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered

Comment: If you see plagiarism, flag the post for moderator attention and explain in the 'other' option what you found, including evidence of where the text was copied from.

Comment: *Preparing pitchforks* Can you post a link to the user in question?

Comment: So, in short, yes, you do need to credit your sources, as not doing so is plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll flag the posts for moderator attention.