# Comments missing in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, global-inbox, top-bar

Just noticed this behaviour for the top 2 items in the inbox:

> [image]

The comments are there, but missing the preview (first 90 characters). They exist in my network profile inbox and are not deleted..

Can I have it back on the top bar inbox as well?

It appears to be specific to comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208630/152859).

Answer (score 10):

I have noticed the same thing, though it *may* not necessarily be a bug.

In the image below, you will notice that if there is **only one comment**, it is displayed.

In the instance that there are **2 or more comments**, they simply *aren't* displayed.

Which comments should be displayed anyways?

Should the oldest or the most recent be shown? Perhaps there should be a feature to collapse/uncollapse them? I'm fine with it, as is. I don't see an issue.

> [image]

Comment: Good catch, looks like you found the actual bug.

Answer (score 3):

@JoshC is correct, we don't show the text in the collapsed group case, since we wouldn't be showing a ver good preview.  It would be misleading as best, so we provide a link but no text there to avoid confusion over what that text is or isn't.

Comment: Makes sense, so it this a bug then? http://i.stack.imgur.com/byPBz.png or was this behaviour only temporary?