# Are quote answers not answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution, blockquote

Many people know that link-only answers are not answers, and they are normally deleted, or downvoted or whatever that happens to them.

Recently, there's been a bit of buzz surrounding whether quote-only answers are not answers. I've started seeing quite a few of them on the sites that I'm most often on (Aviation.SE and Stack Overflow), and I've found that they are information taken from articles or even software documentation. To make matters worse, some don't even attribute the source of where they got it from.

Quotes are great additions to answers, but I feel that quotes alone don't often intend or serve to answer the question in depth. Should these be counted as not an answer, and should we flag/delete/close/whatever these questions?

Comment: I really think this is up to the individual site to decide... there are definitely sites that use this a lot and it's fine because you don't really need any additional info. But, either way, attribution is **required** and anyone who doesn't should be downvoted at least until they add it.

Answer (score 9):

If answers do not attribute the source, then they are instances of blatant plagiarism. This is dealt with in [the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing):

> Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) is how plagiarism should be dealt with.

Also, the help center says something else explicitly:

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.

So officially, these "answers" are not appropriate because they add nothing original.

But I'm nearly guilty of this myself in this answer. So here's my two cents:

Note that above the typing box is the text **"Your Answer"**. Shouldn't this imply that the work presented is original - the work of the person who is responding? This answer is *my answer* - not yours or anyone else's. (Legally, no, I cannot claim this as my work because of how it is licensed, but the idea came from me.) This should mean that the work must be original. Not "An Answer". Not "An Expert Answer". Simply "Your Answer".