# Earlier answer edited to duplicate later answer in full

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

I recently revisited an old answer of mine to an even older question, and was a bit surprised by the changes I saw;

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming) in 2013.  At that point, the question had been asked and "answered" in 2010, but the selected answer simply left a link to some documentation with no real content - the answer in full was as per [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2715214/1).

When I came across this, I then [answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15019443/1678468) with the actual information requested, for the benefit of future visitors.

However, it seems the author of the original non-answer answer subsequently returned and edited theirs, pasting the full content of my answer verbatim into theirs:
[image]

Because theirs was the accepted answer at the start, it now looks to new visitors as if they posted the original content, and my later-dated answer is a redundant duplicate.  Of course they've since been gathering upvotes for the content I originally added.

I was quite surprised by this, and am curious as to whether this is common, or is in any way discouraged on SO?

Is there anything simply stopping me writing "placeholder" answers on new questions, and subsequently duplicating highest-voted content into my own "older" answer?

Comment: As a side note, you say "in full" and "full content", but they didn't copy your _full_ answer into their post. In fact, it's possible they didn't even see your post and got it from a different location. (Not arguing feasibility, just pointing this out.) They didn't even copy the full list of letters and their meanings from your answer, _if_ they copied from your answer. I'm not saying they didn't, I'm not saying they did, just pointing out that they did not add your full answer. (It's also worth noting that this happened some time ago, which may affect the handling.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user is copying answers word for word without attribution, no that isn't allowed and you can flag the question for moderator attention. You could also edit attribution in to the question yourself or suggest OP does so in a comment. See [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/307988).

All user content on Stack Exchange is [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licensed, so they *can* technically copy your answer if they attribute you. But in your specific case...

The copied content is taken word for word from the documentation the original answer linked to and the Markdown for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f6a23b5f-9b56-46d7-8b00-a669da280fa4/view-source) and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/94fc55c1-5891-4605-a22f-87a2d8927c57/view-source) is completely different, so it probably wasn't copied from your answer. The original (i.e. written by you) parts of your answer weren't copied either so at worst the other answer was repeating third-party information you had previously given. What they were really doing though was *including the relevant parts of the link in the question*, [which is *exactly* what you should do when answering with external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). I see no problem there.