# Correct course of action when an answer is nearly word-for-word copied without attribution?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks, external-sources

I was searching "C++ returning array from function" on Google when I noticed that the top two results - Stack Overflow and Tutorialspoint - had exactly the same short description beneath the search result.

I compared the [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968208/4106215) to the [Tutorialspoint page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm) and see that they're *almost* the same, but not exact copies.

I read [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160072/378501) about what to do if plagiarism is suspected, so I thought to check the [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111001000000*/https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm) to see how old the Tutorialspoint page is, and found it's been [unchanged since May 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110522013651/https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm). The Stack Overflow answer is from October 2016.

It seems to me that this answer is on the borderline of Stack Overflow etiquette so, more for my own enlightenment, I'm curious as to what Stack Overflow pros think of this.

In favor of the answerer:

1. An attempt is made to sculpt the Tutorialspoint example to the question asked
2. Links to other pages seems to be frowned upon in answers, so perhaps the answerer thought this was the best way to share what he found to be a good resource
3. This is the only answer the answerer has given so there's no pattern of these type of answers

Against the answerer:

1. The top part of the SO answer is word-for-word copied from the Tutorialspoint page
2. There's no link to the Tutorialspoint page
3. The attempt to sculpt the Tutorialspoint example mostly involves renaming variables
4. The answer itself doesn't add anything above and beyond the other 20-someodd answers to the question

Again, I'm mostly curious about how a seeming edge case like this is handled.