# Pattern of plagiarism - one flag or flag-per-instance?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

I've read [*What to do when plagiarism is discovered*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered), which says this about a pattern of plagiarism:

> If it looks like there is an egregious pattern of plagiarism, and deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention. Explain that you believe the answer has been plagiarized, and paste the source URL into a comment underneath, say `Plagiarism: copied without attribution from ....`

If I've found (say) six examples from a user, should I flag them individually, or raise a single flag on one of them and list all six occurrences?

I don't want to create extra work for mods with multiple flags, but I could easily run out of space in the flag box...

Comment: It depends. If it is one source that got copied all over the place, one flag with links to other instances and an indication if there is more will do. If each post is plagiarized from several sources a per post flag is better. Or at least that is how I try to do it.

Comment: Thanks @rene. This is a case where each answer plagiarises a different source, so I'll flag them individually.

Comment: Yeah, if you revisit helpful flags you'll see Martijn leaving comments like "plagiarized from  *url from your flag text*" and then he hit delete on the post. Make sure your flag text starts with "Plagiarism:"

Comment: One flag per post, with a link to the source, is probably easiest, as it keeps the links organized. It would be a good idea to something like "I've flagged other posts by this user for plagiarism" in each flag. If you've checked 12 of a user's 100 posts and found lots to be plagiarism, then a general flag may be appropriate, as the explanation should signal that there are a lot of other posts still to check. If you've already checked all their other posts and *not* found plagiarism, please mention that, so we don't end up repeating that work by checking the rest of their posts too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've found a user who copied content from *one* source and then posted that all over, raise a single custom flag containing the links to the other posts.  This way you can raise a flag like:

> Answers plagiarised from `<source>`:  `<stick-links-here>`

If you've found multiple answers plagiarizing from *multiple* sources, then raise individual flags so you don't flag it like:

> `<Answer>` plagiarized from `<source>`, `<another answer>` plagiarized from `<another source>`, `<another answer>` plagiarized from `<another source>`

And then fill the box with multiple links to different sources.