# What's the punishment for users who copy their answers from other sources (Quora, etc.) without citing them?

Tags: discussion, citation, reference

I'm curious to know what are the punishment(s) for copy-pasting answers from other sources (not copying an answer from Stack Exchange itself) without citing them.

Comment: Flag for mod karma, I'm sure they will think of something...

Comment: Why would (or should) the penalty be different? Plagiarism is plagiarism.

Comment: Related: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/334566)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) makes it clear that this is not allowed:

> [Plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted.

In practice, what happens will depend upon the extent of this behavior. If a post contains some plagiarized text, but also additional relevant information the poster wrote themselves, the plagiarized text will be edited out, and the poster will be warned against repeating this behavior.

If the post contains *only* plagiarized text, it will be summarily deleted, and again, the poster will be warned about this.

If the poster *repeats* this behavior, they would be considered a [spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), and can face serious consequences such as being suspended from the site. If the poster has no positive contributions, they may even have their account deleted.

Finally, there's no difference between plagiarizing from another Stack Exchange post as opposed to some off-site source. In either case, it's copying other's work without attribution, and that's not allowed.

Comment: And how is a plagiarism detected by moderators? Do they use a software?

Comment: Most plagiarism is detected by regular users like you and me @MovieGoer and brought via moderator flags to attention of mods.

Comment: @MovieGoer Google :)

Comment: @MovieGoer I'm not sure what you mean by 'detected' exactly. As rene pointed out, instances of plagiarism are usually reported by regular users. As DavidPostill points out, simply pasting the text into a search engine will reveal whether it was plagiarized. That's usually what I do to check if some answer is plagiarized.

Comment: @MovieGoer - I am not a moderator.  I start by searching for a sentence.  If that exact sentence is found on another website I look at that website.  If multiple sentences appear in the answer and the website it's an obvious case of plagiarism.  It's extremely easy to detect plagirms without even searching for it.