# Differentiate linked posts by "direction"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Now for each question there is a (very useful!) *Links* section: there we can find all posts (here on SO) linked somehow to this question. It's very helpful to *navigate* the topic.

It differs little bit from how this feature is implemented, for example, for publications. What I would suggest is to split that sections in two sub-sections (**differentiated with an icon, with a sub-title or whatever else**): one for posts linked by current question and another for questions that link current one: Something like:

```
LINKS
-> First referenced post
-> Second reference post
<- Another post that references this
```

Example mockup here - two posts only, to compare with current look:

[image: mockup]

For a better graphical example see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxSzr.png) provided by @Mołot. In article searching this is very helpful to follow the topic (and somehow to quickly evaluate a post). If StackOverflow would be a network of shared technical resources I think 
the same mechanism used for publications will help users (even if, I admit, very few of them) to use it for what it is (or it'll be).

Imagine a post cited by 1000 other posts, it makes clear that it's a fundamental point and make navigation easier (often *in* links are digressions or deeper/specific topics and *out* links are a sort of bibliography).

Well [I would see links managed even better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152519/a-better-way-to-create-links-to-answers) (they seems to me pretty rudimentary for a *network*, sort of huge hyper-text) but this may not be a priority for SO developers so I won't propose it again...

Comment: It would use up a 3 character (on average) wide space there. Or more depending on implementation, but no less if it's to be visible. And this could turn 5-lines titles we sometimes have there now into what, 7 liners? Is it worth it?

Comment: @Mołot of course IMO it worth it!!! Often a good answer (like a good article) is a web of connections (for references, examples, similar questions). It's widely accepted in publications and IMO it is useful here too (to make SO a **reference site**, of course for questions like "why this code doesn't compile?" it's pretty useless). Moreover it may be a single character before title (even color of _vote score_ box near link if supported with proper tooltip).

Comment: Here, I made a test of how it would look like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e1ELV.png note only one post got altered, to show comparison with what is there now.

Comment: @Mołot hmmmm you're right on left doesn't look so nice, it breaks _flow_ and it's too highlighted. I supposed few characters (even one) just before (and inline with) link title (right of box). Something not bigger than 8/10 pixels.

Comment: And now imagine looking at it on Full HD 5 inch phone. It would be what, half a millimetre in size? ;p

Comment: Something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxSzr.png ? I think now arrow is hardly visible and unusable.

Comment: @Mołot yes, something like that! Even smaller. It has not to be _usable_, just slightly visible. About mobile devices...well...layout is so different there that I would even skip this _feature_.

Comment: Of course feel free to use my mockup in your post, if that's what you want. I think it illustrates it more reliable than your pre block ;)

Comment: @Mołot I will, I have no artistic sense...so I don't even try... :)

Comment: I took the liberty to edit it into your question, as you said it's about it. Feel free to rollback if it's not.