# Is it wise to recommend mass deletion?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The suggested FAQ [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/ive-been-accused-of-plagiarism-what-do-i-do) deals with the case that you as a user have been plagiarizing contributions (possibly innocently) and found out.

One of the recommendations on how to fix the situation is to delete those of your own contributions that are plagiarized, and are beyond saving (say, because they essentially consist of *nothing else* but the plagiarized sections.)

Is this a wise thing to recommend, or will this get the user into even more trouble because they will trigger the "ragequit" alarm?

I assume the automatic answer ban won't be triggered, because (presumably) a user's plagiarized content will have upvotes.

Comment: Wrap the advice in an `if`?

Comment: According to Shakespeare _"The fool doth think he is wise, but the wise man knows himself to be a fool."_ Taken to one conclusion you could say that yes it's wise to recommend it but foolish to follow your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...or will this get the user into even more trouble because they will trigger the "ragequit" alarm?

Yes, this might cause a little bit of confusion.  If a user deletes five of their posts in one day, a flag is automatically thrown on those posts.  If those are all 0-score or negatively voted posts, moderators usually just ignore it as clean-up.  If all of those posts are upvoted though, we might assume there's a ragequit in progress and undelete the posts and contact the user.  It's definitely better for them to just add attribution for any plagiarized posts, but they can feel free to delete any that have a 0 or negative score without getting in any additional hot water.

If they just want the posts to be deleted, I suppose they could flag them as "plagiarized from http://example.com", just as anyone else could.

Comment: Your bow tie is near perfectly aligned Mr. Lizard. A fine job.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have shown this person the instruments, it might be better if they made a full confession to the relevant authorities rather than start clicking 'delete' all over. I imagine that the team would be want to accomodate someone who has seen the error of her or his ways.

Comment: That is kinda implied, but might need more clarification. It's in the "what can I do to fix the situation" section though. It could be that the better recommendation is "don't do anything, and wait for the mods to handle it" - but then, the OP knows best which contributions they plagiarized. This is almost impossible for mods to find out, they are busy enough

Comment: Thus my suggestion that they contact the team and tell them where the bad content is.