# How did you get Community ♦ to post a comment?

Tags: support, comments, community-user

Apparently as a joke, somebody got the Community user to post [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161538/are-there-any-robot-moderators-on-so#comment469239_161544) on an answer to [Are there any robot moderators on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161538/are-there-any-robot-moderators-on-so). This is odd, because actions attributed to Community ♦ are normally automated maintenance tasks.

[Community ♦'s comments](https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/-1?page=1&filter=comments) are [normally automated messages from the link-checking script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159113/why-are-all-comments-by-community-user-on-14-may).

Whereas now it's contributing to discussions:

[image: Community posted a comment]

Has it suddenly awakened? How was this done?

Comment: I imagine a developer logged into the Community user and posted a comment... Is that too difficult to imagine?

Comment: If you notice the name "Community ♦" **isn't** a link.

Comment: @animuson Really? Then its plan of deception is working - Did you not know that Community ♦ is really a prototype version of [Skynet?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_%28Terminator%29) ;)

Answer (score 23):

It just does these things, we clocked up the A.I. a little recently, maybe...*too* much?