# Do I have to worry about copyright issues?

Tags: support, legal, copyright

Suppose I find a solution in Google Books, paste it as an answer on Stack Overflow, then provide its link for further studies on that topic. Is it legal to do that?

Comment: [Have you seen this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)? In particular, see the **"How do I properly add attribution in the future"** section.

Comment: @David Robinson i'm giving link of author book so that someone who has asked the question may buy the book to study more or just read those content upto him, but i fear about the copywright issue

Comment: thanks for answer i'll remember this in future

Comment: If my assignment is to write the next great american novel, and I were to copy and paste the text from The Great Gatsby into my answer, then cite F. Scott Fitzgerald, would that be acceptable?  Be careful with copypasting entire answers worth of content.  Cites should support your writing, not the other way around.