# How to use a blog and SO in tandem?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, blog

I have been contributing to SO for some six months. I also have a personal [blog](http://chris-walton.blogspot.com/), which has very little traffic, and to which I contribute only sporadically. I had been thinking of putting some of my questions and answers to SO onto my blog. If I did this it would be pieces which in my opinion reflect some of my better work. Were I to do this, I would also copy relevant answers/questions. I would also ensure that attribution of other people's work were attached to any part of their work. Such attribution would reflect the information available to me on the question/answer as a user of SO. Equally, there are occasions when it is more convenient to write a question or answer on my blog (wider range of editing tools mainly), and then copy or link to it as my contribution to SO.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/is-it-spamming-to-link-to-relevant-sections-in-your-own-blogspot) caused me to think that either or both of these practices are frowned upon by (at least a portion) of the contributors to SO.

What is the general view on the practices I have described?

Comment: Aren't these 2 different questions? (And the latter already handled by the question you linked to?)

Comment: @Arjan - they may be two different questions - I did not see them as such, I saw them both as two aspects of the title question. I don't see the question I have linked to as dealing with my point - that was about somebody linking to his blog continually, rather than occasionally.

Comment: I personally do this somewhat. I have a few posts on my blog that are specifically about common questions on SO so that when they come up I don't have to rewrite everything that needs to be said (e.g., http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML_is_not_regular). Also, I don't post about the same things in both places for the most part. My blog is for in-depth verbose meanderings into software engineering while SO is for calling Jeff Atwood a vampire. Or maybe it's the other way around.

Comment: How about an API for embedding a SO answer on another site (such as a blog)?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first point - as long as you follow the [cc by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license linked to at the foot of every page you are fine to copy questions and answers from Stack Overflow. That means that you must:

> - attribute the work correctly - keep the original author's name attached to the post and make it clear that it came from Stack Overflow
> - allow others to share (with the same license) what you have done.

To answer your second point - by all means link to your blog for more information on an answer, but the important part of the answer - the bit that actually answers the question - should be posted on Stack Overflow. This is so people don't have to visit your blog if they don't want to and also guards against the possibility that your blog goes dark. Also what **is** frowned on is promotion of your blog when it's not relevant to the question/answer.