# Is it ok to answer based someone's older answer on SE?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions)
>   [What to do when plagiarism is discovered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)

This question will probably be closed in a few minutes. It is a duplicate but I couldn't find the question using with meta search.

Anyway, [here is older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667107/447156), [here is the new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221855/447156). In this case, is vote to close the new question as a possible dublicate not the best choice? Looks to me a little bit not ethical.

Comment: Why do you feel that that is a copied answer?

Comment: I feel you are jumping to conclusions here. The code is simple enough, the new answer doesn't have a syntax error like the old one does, and it looks like this is how you sort listboxes in C#. At the very least, benefit of the doubt should be applied here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Comment: Just because answers are similar, it doesn't mean they are copied. Look at this other C# question [C# stored procedure with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201734/c-sharp-stored-procedure-with-parameters) with 8 almost identical answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that, so long as you give proper attribution.

Of course, it is better to add details and making it a *better* answer.

However, if the older answer fully answers the new question, chances are good that the new question is a duplicate of the older one and should be closed as such.

Comment: Not certain they are dupes; don't know enough C# but one is about sorting, general, the other about sorting with datetimes in the listbox. The *answers* may turn out to be the same though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The answers seem to have an identical structure, but they are clearly based on different code bases (variable names and such).

Comment: But most of all, the answers look similar to me because that's how you sort listbox contents. Not sure how you'd come to a different answer in that simple case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - True. When it comes to _simple_ questions, the questions may end up being very different, but the solution and answers to the different questions can easily end up being identical.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?