# Is copying comments a bad thing?

Tags: support, comments, answers, etiquette

Sometime if a user comments on the question, and it is good to add in our answer to make it more helpful under **See Also** section.

Is it good / bad to do this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/is-it-in-bad-form-to-answer-a-question-with-another-users-comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that, as long as you provide attribution.

What I usually do instead of doing a 1:1 copy is to add a paragraph that summarizes that the comment said, like for example

> ... but as @JohnDoe says in the comments, it is also possible to flabber the gargle using quorax.

Comment: No If its just a link and that too internal to SO.

Comment: @org I don't understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: @org oh, you mean a comment that consists only of a link? That should be okay to copy 1:1, maybe with a `thanks @username` as a hat tip

Comment: JohnDoe has no idea what he's talking about.  If you use a quorax to flabber the gargle, the spoofee will raise a `UninitializedTorikException`, and the stack trace from one of those is not pretty, let me tell you.

Comment: @todo that's no longer an issue in the new 2.1 SDK, which comes with a completely rewritten spoofee.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a comment or link posted from another question/comment/answer this is what I think should be done:

- Give attribution to the original poster (as mentioned by Pekka's other trolling acc)

Simply copying it should not be to justify your comment by what's already said but to expand on the previous comment/answer.